# Algebraic number field -> Ring of integers -> "Semiring of naturals?"

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The field of rational numbers has the interesting property that all elements admit a "prime factorization," even though it is a field, in the sense each rational can be expressed as a quotient of two integers which we can factor independently, and then reduce. We would like to develop a similar prime factorization for the positive elements of some other algebraic number field, or at least one which is a UFD. In particular I'm most interested in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$ so I'll just talk about that.

The usual way to do this is to first look at the ring of integers, which in this situation is $\Bbb Z[\phi]$. This ring has $\phi$ as a nontrivial unit, which complicates things a little bit, but at least we can determine the primes in this ring up to multiplication by a power of $\phi$. Then, because $\Bbb Z[\phi]$ generates $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$ as its field of fractions, we can use these "primes" to get something like a prime factorization on the elements of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$, up to multiplication by powers of $\phi$.

I am curious if we can go one step farther to the semiring $\Bbb N[\phi]$ of all elements of the form $a + b\phi$ with $a,b\in \Bbb N$. The idea is, in $\Bbb Z[\phi]$, primes come in equivalence classes which are equivalent up to some power of $\phi$, but for each such equivalence class there is one unique "reduced" prime which is of the form $a+b\phi$ where $a > b \geq 0$. Thus, we know that every prime will have a representative in this semiring, and in fact form a basis for the multiplicative group of the semiring treated as a monoid - except for one missing element, which is $\phi$ itself. In other words, $\phi$ is now "just another prime," or another basis element or whatever you'd like to call it, since it's no longer an invertible unit. We can extend the resulting "prime factorization" on elements of $\Bbb N[\phi]$ to all elements of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$, first using the Grothendieck ring method to generate $\Bbb Z[\phi]$ and then using the field of fractions to get $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$.

The main question I have: does this really work? It sounds nice, but is pretty far from how I learned this stuff, so I've lost my bearings a bit. It is certainly much cleaner to be able to give elements in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$ a prime factorization only up to a factor of $-1$ rather than any power of $\phi$. Is there some hidden snag if we really want to use this to generate a prime factorization? Or, if this technique does work, does it also work on other number fields, and does this technique have a name? Instead of a "ring of integers" it's a "semiring of naturals," I guess.

Comment: If $a+b\phi$ is a representative of a prime, then so is $(a+b\phi)\phi$. This shows that $\phi$ is {\em not} just another prime. What you seem to be talking about is picking a single representative in the first quadrant, which is what Dirichlet does in his proof of the analytic class number formula.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I said above that there is only one representative with $a > b ≥ 0$ and I don't see how that relates to your observation that there are multiple representatives. But how does this relate to the semiring?

Comment: That is a very good point, and in fact it isn't always true. For instance, $(3 + 2\phi)^2 = (13 + 16\phi) = (10+3\phi)\phi^2$. So I guess that if $\phi$ is "prime", then we no longer have unique factorization in this semiring, at least given the way I'm choosing these prime representatives. I'm also not sure what that means for the larger picture of "semirings of naturals" in general.

Comment: (The above comment was in response to a comment that is now deleted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha\in \Bbb{Z}[\phi]_{>0}$ let $$R(\alpha)=\alpha \phi^n$$ with $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ the least integer such that $\alpha \phi^n\in \Bbb{N}[\phi]$.

To get unique factorization in $\Bbb{N}[\phi]-0$ you'd need that
$$R(\alpha)R(\beta)=R(\alpha \beta)$$ But this fails because
$$R(2+\phi)=2+\phi \qquad R((2+\phi)^2)=(2+\phi)^2\phi^{-2}=5$$

> (maybe unique factorization holds if you exclude a few elements like those whose norm is divisible by $5$?)

Comment: This is a good point, although what I'd like to know is if this is just a problem with my naive choice of "reduction" for primes in $\Bbb Z[\phi]$, or if there is something deeper. Does there exist *any* choice of, I guess multiplicative monoid, which *does* have unique factorization and generates $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$ via the method above?

Comment: You meant semiring as multiplicative monoid is trivial

Comment: I guess one way to trivially do this would be to just naively take all of the primes in $\Bbb Z[\phi]$, along with $\phi$ itself, and just form the free commutative monoid of all products. I guess what we are saying, then, is that this won't be all of what I called $\Bbb N[\phi]$. For instance, $5$ won't be in this set at all. This gives what I was originally after, but it's just a monoid rather than a semiring. It's easy to see that you can't get a semiring, then, since if the semiring has $1$ and $\phi$ the semiring thus generated will be $\Bbb N[\phi]$ again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm realizing. I am not sure if this is equivalent to your suggestion of looking at only those elements whose norm isn't divisible by 5, but it makes sense.

Comment: Just to get my head on straight here, is this always possible to do, at least if we have a UFD? For instance, given any algebraic number field, we can look at the ring of integers, and then take the monoid generated by the primes and any basis for the group of units. We could further add the requirement that all elements of this basis be $> 1$. Do we then always generate the original algebraic number field if we take differences and quotients of this monoid? Does the result have some kind of universal property?